# SQL Join on Multiple Tables with Rows Filtered on Condition

Tags: sql, left-join, conditional-statements, inner-join, where-clause

What I have to do is create a sql statement with the following: The salespersons first and last name, their SIN number, the Product SKU, the Product Description, and the Product Price for all of the Unit sales price over $100.00.

This is the information I was provided.
[image]

This is what I have so far:

SELECT s.FirstName, s.LastName, s.SIN, p.SKU, p.ProductDescription, p.Price
FROM Salesmen

Comment: You have table aliases that are not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, SIN, SKU, Price, ProductDescription 
FROM Salesmen 
INNER JOIN ProductSales ON SalesmanId=SellerId 
INNER JOIN Products ON (ProductSales.ProductID=Products.ProductID)
WHERE (Price>100 AND UnitSalesPrice >100)
```

or, with the alternative`WHERE` clause (the condition is not exactly clear from your description):

```
WHERE (Price>100)
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: The WHERE is good to be on the "ProductSales" table to minimize the rows needed to be joined.

Comment: @ThanasisGrammatopoulos Thanks for your thoughtful comments. The OP can modify the WHERE clause correspondingly. Best regards,

Comment: Thank you, it is indeed just the Unit Sales Price over $100.00.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your project. Best regards,